# If I forward declare a function template, may I put the definition after the calling site and not explicit instantiate it at all?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, forward-declaration, function-templates

In a header file of a large project, I have to forward declare a function template before the calling site. The code boils down to this:

```cpp
//H1.h

#pragma once

template <typename>
void f();

inline void g()
{
    f<void>();
}
//POI #1

template <typename>
void f()
{}
```

```cpp
//TU1.cpp

#include "H1.h"

void func1()
{
    g();
}

//(End of TU) POI #2
```

```cpp
//TU2.cpp

#include "H1.h"

void func2()
{
    g();
}

//(End of TU) POI #3
```

As I understand, #1, #2 and #3 are three POIs for `f`. At POI #1, `f` is not defined yet. After the definition of `f`, there is no explicit instantiation to tell the compiler to instantiate `f<void>` specifically. Does the compiler remember to generate code for `f<void>` at the end of TU? The testing result is yes, at least when using [GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/jnz6134qx), clang, or MSVC.

But the question is: is this *declare-call-define* pattern for function template standard conformant?

I'm not a standard expert but I searched the standard text to look for relevant words, and only found [this rule](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#temp.explicit-7) for when using explicit instantiation. But I'm not sure the case when the template is implicit instantiated.

Comment: Why you combine two questions? I vote to close for focus. Yes it is kosher, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255281/necessity-of-forward-declaring-template-functions  Templates and inlines are immune to ODR unless you really define those to conflict in different translation units.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Thanks for the hint. I have removed question 2.

Comment: OK, I retract vote.

Comment: Template instantiation phase follows syntactic and semantic analysis phase, so this looks like you can haz template definition located after its first «use». https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/lex.phases#1.7.sentence-3 https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/lex.phases#1.8

Comment: See also https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp#7